# treant.js can we create two root elements in the chart

Tags: javascript, tree, orgchart, organizational-chart

Hi I am trying to use treant.js for creating org structure. the issue is director and secretary need to be shown in the same line with no connection as all the managers are below director something like shown in the picture can any one tell me how we can acheive this using treant.js
Since this is the only free org chart java script i am using it any other suggestions are welcome 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VOmB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can make them link to a single root node, and then use the option to hide the root node. I had to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was able to achieve it by creating pseudo node as root node and  hide it.